# H2 fulltext search order results

Tags: database, lucene, full-text-search, h2

I have a Table called "AM_API". In which have a column called "NAME".
I am using lucene full text search with h2 database.
I have added about 1000 entries to AM_API table with names "Test1", "Test2", "Test3",............."Test1000"

I have created the lucene full text search index and search is working fine. But the search results order is incorrect.

Following is my query.

`SELECT APIS.* FROM FTL_SEARCH_DATA ('Tes',0,10) FT, AM_API APIS WHERE FT.TABLE='AM_API' AND APIS.UUID=FT.KEYS[0] ORDER BY APIS.NAME`

This query returns results in following order.

Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4, Test5, Test6,Test7, Test8, Test9,Test10

But the correct sorted order should be

Test1, Test10, Test100, Test1000, Test101, Test102,Test103, Test104, Test105,Test106

How to get the full text search data in correct order sorted by name column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing my query to following, it now sorts the results as expected.
`SELECT APIS.*  LEFT JOIN FTL_SEARCH_DATA (?, 0, 0) FT ON API.UUID=FT.KEYS[0] WHERE  FT.TABLE='AM_API' GROUP BY UUID ORDER BY NAME`